# Left and Right Y-axes not formatting correctly

Tags: r, plot, multiple-axes

Say that I want to produce a barplot for the following data (counts):

```
 A     B     C     D 
3030  3049  3104  3018
```

But I also want to put a line plot overlapying the bar plot of the following data(lg):

```
A 2.485294117647059
B 2.465160980297934
C 2.414123006833713
D 2.457267020762916
```

This has been my code so far:

```
b<-barplot(counts,col='black',border=FALSE,axes=FALSE,cex.names = 0.75)

left.axis.pos<-c(quantile(counts))
axis(2,at=left.axis.pos,labels=left.axis.pos,las=2,cex.axis=0.75)
mtext("Number",side=2,line=3,cex=1)

right.axis.ticks<-c(quantile(as.numeric(lg[,2])))
axis(4,at=right.axis.ticks,labels = right.axis.ticks,las=2,cex.axis=0.75)
mtext("ratio",side=4,line=2,cex=1)

lines(lg[,1],as.numeric(lg[,2]), col='grey',lwd=2)
dev.off()
```

However, the y-axis is either too far up (on left) or too far down (on right).

[image]

The original PDF is also [available on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ax0ks5yf1vm0ku0/bar.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to play with settings a little to combine things as intended:

```
oldmar <- par("mar")
par(mar=c(5.1,4.1,4.1,3.1))

b <- barplot(counts,col='black',border=FALSE,axes=FALSE,cex.names = 0.75)
axis(2,cex.axis=0.75, las=2)
mtext("Number",side=2,line=3,cex=1)

par(new=TRUE)
barplot(rep(NA,4),ylim=range(as.numeric(lg[,2])),axes=FALSE)
axis(4, cex.axis=0.75, las=2)
lines(b, as.numeric(lg[,2]),col="grey",lwd=2)

box()
par(mar=oldmar)
par(new=FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is doing exactly what you are telling it to.  Have you looked at the values of `left.axis.pos` and `right.axis.ticks`?

It is very unusual to use `quantile` to choose tick positions, it is giving values corresponding to the minimum, maximum, and the 3 quartiles (since you are using the default arguments).  More common is to use values that span the entire range of the plot (include 0 for the barplot) and are equally spaced.  Look at the `pretty` function and possibly `range` or `max`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've been doing a lot of graphing with factors using ggplot2 so going back to basics takes a bit of getting used to.